# Best way to define private methods for a class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, code-completion

I just started programming Objective-C and, having a background in Java, wonder how people writing Objective-C programs deal with private methods.

I understand there may be several conventions and habits and think about this question as an aggregator of the best techniques people use dealing with private methods in Objective-C.

Please include an argument for your approach when posting it. Why is it good? Which drawbacks does it have (that you know of) and how you deal with them?

---

As for my findings so far.

It is possible to use [categories](http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html#categories) [e.g. MyClass (Private)] defined in MyClass.m file to group private methods.

This approach has 2 issues:

1. Xcode (and compiler?) does not check if you define all methods in private category in corresponding @implementation block
2. You have to put @interface declaring your private category in the begin of MyClass.m file, otherwise Xcode complains with a message like "self may not respond to message "privateFoo".

The first issue can be worked around with [empty category](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/chapter_4_section_5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2) [e.g. MyClass ()].
The second one bothers me a lot. I'd like to see private methods implemented (and defined) near the end of the file; I do not know if that's possible.

Comment: Folks might find this question interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158660/why-doesnt-objective-c-support-private-methods

Comment: Why not just [leave out the declaration of the private method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767129/objective-c-should-i-declare-private-methods)?

Answer (score 443):

There isn't, as others have already said, such a thing as a private method in Objective-C. However, starting in Objective-C 2.0 (meaning Mac OS X Leopard, iPhone OS 2.0, and later) you can create a category with an empty name (i.e. `@interface MyClass ()`) called *Class Extension*. What's unique about a class extension is that the method implementations must go in the same `@implementation MyClass` as the public methods. So I structure my classes like this:

In the .h file:

```
@interface MyClass {
    // My Instance Variables
}

- (void)myPublicMethod;

@end
```

And in the .m file:

```
@interface MyClass()

- (void)myPrivateMethod;

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)myPublicMethod {
    // Implementation goes here
}

- (void)myPrivateMethod {
    // Implementation goes here
}

@end
```

I think the greatest advantage of this approach is that it allows you to group your method implementations by functionality, not by the (sometimes arbitrary) public/private distinction.

Comment: and it will generate a "MYClass may not respond to '-myPrivateMethod- ", not an exception/error.

Comment: This is actually starting to show up in Apple's boilerplate code. ++

Comment: with the LLVM 4 compiler and onwards, you don't even need to do this. you can just define them within your implementation without needing to put them in a class extension.

Comment: If you get the warnings @Comptrol mentions, it's because you've defined a method below rather than above another method that calls it (see Andy's answer) -- and you ignore these warnings at your peril. I made this mistake and the compiler muddled through alright until I nested a call like this: `if (bSizeDifference && [self isSizeDifferenceSignificant:fWidthCombined])...` Then fWidthCombined was always coming through as 0.

Comment: @Wienke It's no longer necessary to worry about the order. Recent versions of LLVM will find the method even if it appears below where it's called.

Answer (score 55):

There isn't really a "private method" in Objective-C, if the runtime can work out which implementation to use it will do it. But that's not to say that there aren't methods which aren't part of the documented interface. For those methods I think that a category is fine. Rather than putting the `@interface` at the top of the .m file like your point 2, I'd put it into its own .h file. A convention I follow (and have seen elsewhere, I think it's an Apple convention as Xcode now gives automatic support for it) is to name such a file after its class and category with a + separating them, so `@interface GLObject (PrivateMethods)` can be found in `GLObject+PrivateMethods.h`. The reason for providing the header file is so that you can import it in your unit test classes :-).

By the way, as far as implementing/defining methods near the end of the .m file is concerned, you can do that with a category by implementing the category at the bottom of the .m file:

```
@implementation GLObject(PrivateMethods)
- (void)secretFeature;
@end
```

or with a class extension (the thing you call an "empty category"), just define those methods last. Objective-C methods can be defined and used in any order in the implementation, so there's nothing to stop you putting the "private" methods at the end of the file.

Even with class extensions I will often create a separate header (`GLObject+Extension.h`) so that I can use those methods if required, mimicking "friend" or "protected" visibility.

Since this answer was originally written, the clang compiler has started doing two passes for Objective-C methods. This means you can avoid declaring your "private" methods completely, and whether they're above or below the calling site they'll be found by the compiler.

Answer (score 39):

While I am no Objective-C expert, I personally just define the method in the implementation of my class. Granted, it must be defined before (above) any methods calling it, but it definitely takes the least amount of work to do.

Comment: This solution has the advantage that it avoids adding superfluous program structure just to avoid a compiler warning.

Comment: I tend to do this as well, but also am not an Objective-C expert. For the experts, is there any reason not to do it this way (aside from the method ordering issue)?

Comment: Method ordering seems to be a minor issue, but if you translate it into **code readability** it can become quite an important issue especially when working in a team.

Comment: Method ordering is no longer significant. Recent versions of LLVM don't care what order the methods are implemented. So you can suit yourself on the ordering, without needing to declare first.

Comment: See also [this response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16758022/1877426) from @justin

Answer (score 24):

Defining your private methods in the `@implementation` block is ideal for most purposes. Clang will see these within the `@implementation`, regardless of declaration order. There is no need to declare them in a class continuation (aka class extension) or named category.

In some cases, you will need to declare the method in the class continuation (e.g. if using the selector between the class continuation and the `@implementation`).

`static` functions are very good for particularly sensitive or speed critical private methods.

A convention for naming prefixes can help you avoid accidentally overriding private methods (I find the class name as a prefix safe).

Named categories (e.g. `@interface MONObject (PrivateStuff)`) are not a particularly good idea because of potential naming collisions when loading. They're really only useful for friend or protected methods (which are very rarely a good choice). To ensure you are warned of incomplete category implementations, you should actually implement it:

```
@implementation MONObject (PrivateStuff)
...HERE...
@end
```

Here's a little annotated cheat sheet:

MONObject.h

```
@interface MONObject : NSObject

// public declaration required for clients' visibility/use.
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) bool publicBool;

// public declaration required for clients' visibility/use.
- (void)publicMethod;

@end
```

MONObject.m

```
@interface MONObject ()
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) bool privateBool;

// you can use a convention where the class name prefix is reserved
// for private methods this can reduce accidental overriding:
- (void)MONObject_privateMethod;

@end

// The potentially good thing about functions is that they are truly
// inaccessible; They may not be overridden, accidentally used,
// looked up via the objc runtime, and will often be eliminated from
// backtraces. Unlike methods, they can also be inlined. If unused
// (e.g. diagnostic omitted in release) or every use is inlined,
// they may be removed from the binary:
static void PrivateMethod(MONObject * pObject) {
    pObject.privateBool = true;
}

@implementation MONObject
{
    bool anIvar;
}

static void AnotherPrivateMethod(MONObject * pObject) {
    if (0 == pObject) {
        assert(0 && "invalid parameter");
        return;
    }

    // if declared in the @implementation scope, you *could* access the
    // private ivars directly (although you should rarely do this):
    pObject->anIvar = true;
}

- (void)publicMethod
{
    // declared below -- but clang can see its declaration in this
    // translation:
    [self privateMethod];
}

// no declaration required.
- (void)privateMethod
{
}

- (void)MONObject_privateMethod
{
}

@end
```

Another approach which may not be obvious: a C++ type can be both very fast and provide a much higher degree of control, while minimizing the number of exported and loaded objc methods.

Comment: +1 for using the full class name as the method name prefix! It's much safer than just an underscore or even your own TLA. (What if the private method is in a library that you use in another of your projects and you forget that you've already used the name, sometime a year or two ago...?)

Answer (score 14):

You could try defining a static function below or above your implementation that takes a pointer to your instance. It will be able to access any of your instances variables.

```
//.h file
@interface MyClass : Object
{
    int test;
}
- (void) someMethod: anArg;

@end


//.m file    
@implementation MyClass

static void somePrivateMethod (MyClass *myClass, id anArg)
{
    fprintf (stderr, "MyClass (%d) was passed %p", myClass->test, anArg);
}


- (void) someMethod: (id) anArg
{
    somePrivateMethod (self, anArg);
}

@end
```

Comment: Apple reserved names with a leading underscore for its own uses.

Comment: And what if you don't use Apple's frameworks? I frequently develop Objective-C code without Apple's frameworks, in fact I build on Linux, Windows and Mac OS X. I removed it anyway considering most people who code in Objective-C probably do use it on Mac OS X.

Comment: I think this is truly private method in .m file. Other class category methods are actually not private because you just cannot put private for methods in @interface...@end block.

Comment: Why would you do that? if you simply add "-" at the beginning of the method definition, you will be to access "self" without passing as a parameter.

Comment: @Guy: because then the method is detectable by reflection, and therefore not private at all.

Answer (score 3):

every objects in Objective C conform to NSObject protocol, which holds onto the **performSelector:** method. I was also previously looking for a way to create some "helper or private" methods that I did not need exposed on a public level. If you want to create a private method with no overhead and not having to define it in your header file then give this a shot...

define the your method with a similar signature as the code below...

```
-(void)myHelperMethod: (id) sender{
     // code here...
}
```

then when you need to reference the method simply call it as a selector...

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myHelperMethod:)];
```

this line of code will invoke the method you created and not have an annoying warning about not having it defined in the header file.

Comment: In this way you have no way to pass a third parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You could use blocks?

```
@implementation MyClass

id (^createTheObject)() = ^(){ return [[NSObject alloc] init];};

NSInteger (^addEm)(NSInteger, NSInteger) =
^(NSInteger a, NSInteger b)
{
    return a + b;
};

//public methods, etc.

- (NSObject) thePublicOne
{
    return createTheObject();
}

@end
```

I'm aware this is an old question, but it's one of the first I found when I was looking for an answer to this very question. I haven't seen this solution discussed anywhere else, so let me know if there's something foolish about doing this.

Comment: What you've done here is create a global block-type variable, which isn't really any better than a function (and not even truly private, since it isn't declared `static`). But I've been experimenting with assigning blocks to private ivars (from the init method) — kinda JavaScript-style — which also allows access to private ivars, something not possible from static functions. Not yet sure which I prefer.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to avoid the `@interface` block at the top you could always put the private declarations in another file `MyClassPrivate.h` not ideal but its not cluttering up the implementation.

MyClass.h

```
interface MyClass : NSObject {
 @private
  BOOL publicIvar_;
  BOOL privateIvar_;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL publicIvar;
//any other public methods. etc
@end
```

MyClassPrivate.h

```
@interface MyClass ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL privateIvar;
//any other private methods etc.
@end
```

MyClass.m

```
#import "MyClass.h"
#import "MyClassPrivate.h"
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize privateIvar = privateIvar_;
@synthesize publicIvar = publicIvar_;

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

One more thing that I haven't seen mentioned here - Xcode supports .h files with "_private" in the name. Let's say you have a class MyClass - you have MyClass.m and MyClass.h and now you can also have MyClass_private.h. Xcode will recognize this and include it in the list of "Counterparts" in the Assistant Editor.

```
//MyClass.m
#import "MyClass.h"
#import "MyClass_private.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way of getting around issue #2. That's just the way the C compiler (and hence the Objective-C compiler) work. If you use the XCode editor, the function popup should make it easy to navigate the `@interface` and `@implementation` blocks in the file.

Answer (score 1):

There is a benefit of private methods absence. You can move the logic that you intended to hide to the separate class and use it as delegate. In this case you can mark delegate object as private and it will not be visible from outside. Moving logic to the separate class (maybe several) makes better design of your project. Cause your classes become simpler and your methods are grouped in classes with proper names.

Answer (score 0):

As other people said defining private methods in the `@implementation` block is OK for most purposes.

On the topic of **code organization** - I like to keep them together under `pragma mark private` for easier navigation in Xcode

```
@implementation MyClass 
// .. public methods

# pragma mark private 
// ...

@end
```