# Can I remove the @private generated by Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, dynamic, private

What is the `@private` for in the file generated by Core Data below? I know [what @private means in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844658/what-does-private-mean-in-objective-c), but there are not instance variables listed after it, so can't I just take it out?

```
//
//  Event.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Event : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * timestamp;

@end


//
//  Event.m
//  

#import "Event.h"


@implementation Event
@dynamic id;

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can safely take it out, it won't change the semantics of your class. If you're not statisfied with what XCode generates for you (though it's a reasonable default), I'd suggest you take a look at  https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check out mogenerator. I passed on it once before, but I think it's time... not just for making model changes easier, but also being able to track the changes with git. The files in the `.xcdatamodel` bundle are binary, so I can't see the diffs.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it doesn't hurt. If you generate the model again it will just put it back.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode now defaults to generating classes with `@private` for instance variables, which you are supposed to declare in case you need them. You can safely remove that `@private` since, as you’ve already noticed, there are no instance variables. In fact, that class declaration is equivalent to

```
@interface Event : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * timestamp;   
@end
```