# Are class methods inherited too?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, subclass, class-method

When I define a new class inheriting from `NSObject`:

```
@interface Photo : NSObject
{
    NSString* caption;
    NSString* photographer;
}

@property NSString* caption;
@property NSString* photographer;

@end
```

are all the **class methods** (like `alloc`) in `NSObject` inherited by the new class `Photo`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `Photo` can use any method/property/ivar/etc (except for those iVars declared `@private`) of a [`NSObject`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) when you subclass [`NSObject`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
Photo *myPhoto;
myPhoto = [[Photo alloc] init];
// ... Do some myPhoto stuff ...
NSLog(@"Photo object: %@", myPhoto);
NSLog(@"Photo description: %@", [myPhoto description]);
NSLog(@"Photo caption: %@", [myPhoto caption]);
NSLog(@"Photo photographer: %@", [myPhoto photographer]);
```

More about `@private` -> [SO Question: what-does-private-mean-in-objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844658/what-does-private-mean-in-objective-c)

[`NSObject` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Might want to modify your answer: neither methods nor properties have access levels (e.g. `@private`.) And even ivars (which do have access levels) can be accessed via the Objective-C runtime.

Comment: The `@private` compiler directive only applies to instance variables, not methods. Also, the dot syntax shouldn't be used to invoke anything other than accessor methods, and `NSObject` doesn't have any accessors. From the Objective-C Programming Guide: "Objective-C also provides a dot (.) operator that offers a compact and convenient syntax for invoking an object’s accessor methods." http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW1

Comment: I don't believe this answers the question; all the methods in the example are instance methods, but the question is specifically about _class_ methods.

Comment: That said, it is true that class methods are inherited, as the class's metaclass is a subclass of the superclass's metaclass. http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html