# What's preferable Categories or Private Attributes in the Interface

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

What's preferable and a clean solution for attributes in a class. Use categories (anonymous) or @private annotation in the interface definition (.h file).
The attributes should not be inherited by other classes.

BR,
mybecks

Answer (score 1):

Categories and @private are two different things.  Categories extend the classes where you can add methods to a class and @private is where other classes can't access your attributes directly and will have to use your accessors.  If you want ivars that subclasses can't access, use @private in your interface.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
@private
int num; //private attribute where subclass can't access
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First up read this to understand the `@private` modifier [What does "@private" mean in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844658/what-does-private-mean-in-objective-c)

And then to answer your questions.

An anonymous category is called a `class extension` and this is what I use to keep my API's clean and to not publicly announce my ivars.

e.g

```
// .h
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@end

// .m
@interface MyClass ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *someDateImWorkingWith;

@end

@implementation MyClass

@synthesize someDateImWorkingWith = _someDateImWorkingWith;

@end
```

As a result I have the `NSDate *someDateImWorkingWith` to use within my class but no one importing my header will even know it exists without doing a little bit of digging. This works well for me your milage may vary.