# Objective-C Access @private instance variables from another class

Tags: objective-c, access-modifiers, private-members

I've been looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844658/what-does-private-mean-in-objective-c) and came across the following code in one of the answers

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    @private
    int someVar;  // Can only be accessed by instances of MyClass

    @public
    int aPublicVar;  // Can be accessed by any object
}
@end
```

Is there anyway to access `someVar` from any other class (including derived classes)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with most dynamic languages you can get at this information in Objective C, however, it is painful.  [Look here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299841/objective-c-introspection-reflection).

Comment: You *can*, but you *shouldn't*. If it's been declared `@private`, it's usually for a good reason.

Comment: @darvids0n I'm not questioning whether you should or shouldn't, that's pretty obvious, I'm just wondering if you can.

Answer (score 0):

No. That's exactly what `@private` means. The compiler explicitly disallows any other class (even subclasses) from accessing that ivar.

`@public` means anyone can access the ivar, and `@protected` means subclasses can access it but other classes can't.