# Private methods using Categories in Objective-C: calling super from a subclass

Tags: objective-c, methods, private, categories, super

I was reading how to implement private methods in Objective-C ([Best way to define private methods for a class in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172598/best-way-to-define-private-methods-for-a-class-in-objective-c)) and a question popped up in my mind:

**How do you manage to implement protected methods, i.e. private methods that are visible to subclasses?**

Suppose I have a MySuperClass with a Category containing all its private methods, and I want to implement a MySubclass overriding or calling super to one of the MySuperClass private methods. Is that possible (using the Categories approach towards implementing private methods)?

Take a look at some of this code, at the bottom there is the overriden method.

```
// ===========================
// = File: MySuperClass.h
// = Interface for MySuperClass
// ===========================

@interface MySuperClass : Object
...
@end

// ===========================
// = File: MySuperClass.m
// ===========================
#import "MySuperClass.h"

// =================================
// = Interface for Private methods
// =================================
@interface MySuperClass (Private)

-(void) privateInstanceMethod; 

@end

// =====================================
// = Implementation of Private methods
// =====================================
@implementation MySuperClass (Private)

-(void) privateInstanceMethod
{
  //Do something
}

@end

// ================================
// = Implementation for MySuperClass
// ================================
@implementation MySuperClass
... 
@end




// ===========================
// = File: MySubClass.h
// = Interface for MySubClass
// ===========================

@interface MySubClass : MySuperClass
...
@end


// ================================
// = Implementation for MySubClass
// ================================

#import MySubClass.h

@implementation MySubClass
//OVERRIDING a Super Private method.
-(void) privateInstanceMethod
{
  [super privateInstanceMethod]; //Compiler error, privateInstanceMethod not visible!
  //Do something else
}
@end
```

Hopefully somebody already figured this out.

Cheers!

Comment: "Luckily somebody already figured this out."... So what are you asking?

Comment: Language confusion, I think. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you nall for making my question easier for everybody to understand. I made a mistake using the word "luckily" when I was actually meaning "hopefully". Sorry and thank you very much!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[This GNUStep page](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/ProgrammingManual/manual_4.html) describes one approach Section 4.5:

> ...The bright side of this is it
>   allows you to simulate protected
>   methods as well. For this, the writer
>   of a subclass must be informed in some
>   way about the protected methods, and
>   they will need to put up with the
>   compiler warnings. Alternatively, you
>   could declare the Protected category
>   in a separate interface file (e.g.,
>   "PointProtected.h"), and provide this
>   interface file with the understanding
>   that it should only be imported and
>   used by a subclass's interface file.

Comment: This is how I do it.  Just put the method declarations in a category header, but implement them in the main implementation block.  Then the files that need to know about the method just have to `#import` the header.

Answer (score 13):

At Apple, when they build the frameworks the typical pattern is to have a public header (MyClass.h) and a private header (MyClass_private.h), and only copy the public headers into the build product.  The .m file will #import both of them, of course.