# private methods in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to define private methods for a class in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172598/best-way-to-define-private-methods-for-a-class-in-objective-c)

Hi, 
Can i have private methods for any class in a cocoa application?
if yse, how?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158660/why-doesnt-objective-c-support-private-methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can!

in your *.m file (Implementation)

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@interface MyClass() 
- (void)privateMethod();
@end 

@implementation MyClass

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)privateMethod
{
   NSlog(@"myPrivateMethod");
}
@end
```

Comment: This is the best you can do in Obj-C, but note that it is not truly private -- another class can still invoke the private method, (albeit with a compile-time warning `'MyClass' may not respond to '-privateMethod'`). See the detailed answers to the linked questions.

Answer (score 0):

If program Java, for example, I'd say to you that private methods are not simple to implement.

To implement them, you should  implement, in the .m file, interfaces containing the signature of those methods you want to be private. 
Since imports "always" regards to .h files, this solution serves as private method implementation solution.

Resuming: use .h to expose your public methods. Use interfaces inside the .m to enable methods to be used as private.