# Forward declaration of objective-c class extension method

Tags: objective-c, class-extensions

The following code produces error *No visible @interface for 'Bar' declares the selector 'barMethod'* on the second line of implementation of `-[Foo fooMethod]`:

```
//  FooBar.m

#import "FooBar.h"

//////////////////////////////////

@implementation Foo

- (void)fooMethod {
    Bar *bar = [Bar new];
    [bar barMethod]; // Error: No visible @interface for 'Bar' declares the selector 'barMethod'
}

@end

//////////////////////////////////

@interface Bar ()
- (void)barMethod;
@end

@implementation Bar

- (void)barMethod {
    // do something
}

@end
```

Is there any way to forward declare `-[Bar barMethod]` inside FooBar.m other than moving `Bar` class extension above `Foo` implementation (which is not very convenient at times)?

Comment: Closely related: [Use class extension for selective visibility in ObjC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7110525)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Nice workaround, but changing the order is easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extension's interface is like any other for purposes of method visibility: the compiler has to see the declaration *before* the use.* Unfortunately, you will have to put the `@interface` either into a header or further up in the file than `Foo`'s implementation.

---

*The one exception to this that I know of is for methods that are not named in an interface at all -- essentially declared by their definition -- and used within the same `@implementation` block. The compiler *will* figure that out for you regardless of the order.