# Objective-C class extensions vs private method or variable

Tags: objective-c

Im not understanding why people use extensions to make variables private instead of just declaring them only in the implementation file ?

Take a look at this code one using extension and one using a instance variable:

```
//this is an extension
@interface MyClass () {
  NSString *myInstanceVariable;
}
// ...
@end
or in the class implementation:

@implementation MyClass {
  NSString *myInstanceVariable;
}
// ...
@end
```

both give me instance variables that would be private. Why would i choose a extension instead of the 2nd approach of just declaring a instance variable ?

Comment: I never use a class extension for private variables. It's a lot more typing if all you want are private ivars. I only use the class extension to add private properties or declare privately that my class conforms to one or more protocols.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for (or at least can be helpful): http://stackoverflow.com/a/13573236/3402095

Comment: [Use class extension for selective visibility in ObjC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7110525)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are declaring variables in an `@interface`, it exposes details of the implementation to users of the class.

If you are declaring variables in an `@implementation` it keeps their existence private and is not visible to someone who only imports the h file.

Edit: For more concise answer. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566862/where-to-put-ivars-in-modern-objective-c)

Comment: How does this answer the question? This makes no attempt to answer why to use one or the other approach.