# difference between view controller and normal model class when declaring property?

Tags: objective-c

i was just figuring out how to have private variable with class extension.
And what i noticed was that there is no default code for **class extension** inside a normal class.
And when i try to declare variable with **@property**, it does not allow me but to type **@protected** and **@private** while inside ViewController, it only allow me to have **@property** **@optional** **@required**.

SO, my question is that is there any reason for that..? What is the difference and what makes it different..?

Comment: By virtue of putting it in the .m file rather than the .h everything you declare will be private

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post any code, leaving us to infer what you're doing. I'm going to assume it's something like this:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property id someProperty; // This works

@private
id someVar; // This does not work

@end
```

and:

```
@implementation ModelClass
{
  @property id someProperty; // This does not work

  @private
  id someVar; // This works
}

@end
```

Assuming that's true, it seems you're confused about the nature of properties vs. instance variables. @property is essentially a way to declare accessor *methods*, for which the compiler (by default) automatically synthesizes method implementations and a corresponding backing instance variable. Instance variables on the other hand, are simply per-instance *variables*, not methods at all.

The first block of code above is a class extension on `ViewController`. Class extensions allow you to declare additional methods -- and thereby @properties too -- separately from the main/public interface for a class.

The braces after `@implementation` in the second block denote a place to declare additional instance variables (only).

`@protected` and `@private` are visibility modifiers for instance variable declarations, and control whether an instance variable is visible only to instances of the class itself (`@private`), instances of the class and its subclasses (`@protected`), or publicly (`@public`). These modifiers cannot be used for methods (of which @properties are a special case). Afterall, in Objective-C, methods are actually always public in the sense that it's only at runtime that a message send is turned into a method call, and the compiler can't truly enforce a limitation on calls to "private" methods.

Finally, to answer what I think is the heart of your question, you most certainly *can* add a class extension to your model class in order to declare additional "private" @properties and other methods. Xcode may not include one in the default new file template for non-view controllers, but that doesn't mean you can't add one yourself:

```
@interface ModelClass ()

@property id somePrivateProperty; // Works just fine

@end
```

Comment: THank you SO much ! btw, could you explain little bit more about this sentence please..? Afterall, in Objective-C, methods are actually always public in the sense that it's only at runtime that a message send is turned into a method call, and the compiler can't truly enforce a limitation on calls to "private" methods.

Comment: what if i put my method declaration in that extension..?

Comment: Regarding that sentence: see bbum's [excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2159027/344733). You can declare regular methods, and @properties in a class extension.