# Get only public methods of an obj-c class

Tags: objective-c, reflection

I can get all the methods of an objc class pretty easily, using

```
Class targetClass = [AClass class];
unsigned int methodClass = 0;
Method *methods = class_copyMethodList(targetClass, methodClass);
```

But I want to know if there is a way that I can get *only* the public methods of this class, either through another call I don't know about or by filtering this list.  Visibility is arguably a joke in objc anyway, but I have to assume that *something* out there will let me do this.

Comment: See [Best way to define private methods for a class in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172598/best-way-to-define-private-methods-for-a-class-in-objective-c) and [Why doesn't Objective-C support private methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158660/why-doesnt-objective-c-support-private-methods)