# Since when does Xcode no longer require forward method declarations and why?

Tags: xcode, llvm

I noticed that Xcode (or more precisely the Apple LLVM compiler?) does not longer require forward method declarations. In other words, the following code builds without warnings:

```
@implementation Foo

-(void) foo {
    [self bar];
}

-(void) bar {}

@end
```

This used to throw a warning in `-foo` saying that `Foo` might not respond to `-bar`, right? Is the compiler smarter now or is this something else? I’m using Xcode 4.3.1 plus Apple LLVM compiler 3.1.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't included `bar` declaration from the header file of `@interface Foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has definitely changed, and it looks like such forward declarations are not required in Xcode 4.3 & later. Cf.
[Private Methods in Objective-C, in Xcode 4.3 I no longer need to declare them in my implementation file ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414410).

Answer (score 0):

In my XCode 4.2, the warning is still there, moreover, when ARC is enabled, it is an error, not just a warning.

Comment: Not if you call and implement the method in the same file. If he'd done [foo bar] from another file, it would error, but it seems fine in the situation above.

Comment: @jrturton I have it implemented right below in the same file and it is still an error.

Comment: Try in 4.3? I've noticed this too, I think it's a compiler feature