# Why is the call to the function "sample_mean" ambiguous?

Tags: c++, xcode, function

I'm writing a program with xcode to do some statistical analysis. However, when I'm building the function for computing the sample variance, xcode keeps telling me that my call the function `sample_mean` (which is also function defined by me) is ambiguous.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>


//sample_mean
double sample_mean (std::vector<double> v);


//sample_variance
double sample_variance (std::vector<double> v);



int main()
{
    std::cout<<"hello world";
}


//sample_mean
double sample_mean (const std::vector<double>& v)
{
    double sum= 0;
    int i=0; for (; i<v.size(); ++i)
    {
        sum= sum+ v[i];
    }
    return sum/v.size();
}



//sample_variance
double sample_variance (const std::vector<double>& v)
{
    double average= sample_mean(v);
    double sum=0;
    int i=0; for (; i<v.size(); ++i)
    {
        sum= sum+ std::pow((v[i]-average), 2);
    }
    return sum/v.size();
}
```

This code contains only the definition of `sample_mean` and `sample_variance`, but the compiler keeps telling me that the function call of `sample_mean` inside the definition of `sample_variance` (which is `double average= sample_mean(v);`) is ambiguous. What is wrong with my program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definitions have different signatures than the declarations.

Simple cure: move the definitions *above* `main`, and forget about forward-declaring the functions.

Forward-declaring the functions is a C-ism, not a particularly bright idea in C++. It just adds work, and creates problems. As you discovered.

Comment: It could even work without moving the functions above `main`, as the compiler used by Xcode [got smarter about this recently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884533).

Comment: @zoul: well, standard C++ is standard C++. standard C++ requires a declaration (which can be a definition) before use. language extensions are language extensions, and other languages are other languages.

Comment: Given that he’s using Xcode, we could be talking Objective-C++. I don’t know the relation between standard C++ and Objective-C++, but maybe the feature I was talking about only works for Objective-C methods anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 methods called `sample_mean`, not just one, and both can be called:

```
double sample_mean (const std::vector<double>& v)
```

and

```
double sample_mean (std::vector<double> v)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have a function declaration `double sample_mean (std::vector<double>)` and then you have a function definition `double sample_mean (const std::vector<double>&)`. These are treated as identifiers of two different functions.