# In Xcode 4.3, can I require forward method declarations as before

Tags: objective-c, xcode, forward-declaration, xcode4.3

Prior to Xcode 4.3, if you wanted to use a method before you declared its implementation, you were required to forward declare the method (as with a C function prototype). This would usually be done in a class continuation (AKA class extension, private category). There's a good example in this question: [Private Methods in Objective-C, in Xcode 4.3 I no longer need to declare them in my implementation file ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414410).

As of 4.3, this is no longer required; DRYers rejoice.

But can this magic be turned off, returning to the pre-4.3 behavior?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want the warnings? Is it so people using older tools don't get build warnings you can't see?

Comment: Some folks find class continuations as useful as header files to see "private" methods at a glance.

Comment: You also want the warning when you share code between Xcode 4.3 and 4.2 users. Otherwise the Xcode 4.3 users check-in code that won't compile under Xcode 4.2.

Comment: @Sandy You can still add forward declarations if you like, and if you do the compiler will still warn if they are NOT implemented. FWIW: Clicking on the end of the "Jump Bar" is how I scan the methods in a class http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-jump_bar/Recipe.html

Comment: @EricS the best suggestion I can offer is to make a scheme that uses "LLVM GCC 4.2" as the compiler, since it will warn, and build with it before checking in. I know this isn't great, and may not work if you use features that require LLVM :-(

Comment: @VincentGable Unfortunately, without anything to enforce forward declaration at build time, it's inevitable that methods would get missed. I think we'll just have to remove this requirement from our team's coding standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently this is not possible. The parsing behavior for Objective-C was changed  to no longer require forward declarations.

Comment: I just confirmed that even with -Weverything enabled, this does not result in an error.  So there appears to be no warning flag to get the behavior desired by Clay.