# objective c accessing public method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield, public-method

I try to access a public method from another class. I already tried many examples I found in the web, but they didn't work in the way I wanted them to.

Class1.h

```
@interface anything : NSObject {

    IBOutlet NSTextField *label;

}

+ (void) setLabel:(NSString *)string;
- (void) changeLabel:(NSString *)string2;
```

Class1.m

```
+ (void) setLabel:(NSString *)string {

    Class1 *myClass1 = [[Class1 alloc] init];

    [myClass1 changeLabel:string];
    NSLog(@"setLabel called with string: %@", string);

}

- (void) changeLabel:(NSString *)string2 {

    [label setStringValue:string2];
    NSLog(@"changeLabel called with string: %@", string2);
}
```

Class2.m

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {

    [Class1 setLabel:@"Test"];

}
```

Very strange is that in the NSLogs, everything is fine, in both NSLogs, the string is "Test", but the textField's stringValue doesn't change!

Comment: You mixed up class and object methods.

The example doesn't really make sense.
You just temporarily create an object in `+ setLabel:`, but you never do something with it/never return it.

Tell me what you want to do so I can help you.

Comment: Why are using a static method? Is that a singleton?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri No it's not singleton, that would require a static variable.

Comment: Yeah I see it well now, he's allocating a new class instance: non sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here a short example for what you can do:

---

## The Custom Class

```
@interface ITYourCustomClass : NSObject
@property (strong) NSString *title;

- (void)doSomethingWithTheTitle;
@end

@implementation ITYourCustomClass
- (void)doSomethingWithTheTitle {
    NSLog(@"Here's my title: %@", self.title);
}
@end
```

---

## Using it

```
@implementation ITAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    ITYourCustomClass *objectOfYourCustomClass = [[ITYourCustomClass alloc] init];
    [objectOfYourCustomClass doSomethingWithTheTitle];
}

@end
```

---

## Class and object methods

Declaring a method with **+** means, that you can call the method directly on a class.
Like you did it with `[myClass1 setLabel:@"something"];`.
This doesn't make sense. What you want, is creating a property.
A property is saved in an object, so you can create an object `ITYourCustomClass *objectOfYourCustomClass = [[ITYourCustomClass alloc] init];` and setting the properties `objectOfYourCustomClass.title = @"something"`. Then you can call `[objectOfYourCustomClass doSomethingWithTheTitle];`, which is a public object method.

Comment: okay.. I think I got something wrong with these + and - I am new to mac development, I develop iPhone apps for 2 years now. I connected Class1 and Class2 to two different nib files which are loaded and one contains a label and the other a textfield, I just want to change the label in the one window with the textfield in the other window. With the example you gave me, I get exactly the same thing as before: the NSLogs give me my changed title but the label itself doesn't change if I call -doSomethingWithTheTitle from another class

Comment: @VincentFriedrich So how do you use Class1 and Class2 in Interface Builder? You usually have a view controller, or a window controller where you manage such things. Or you can add objects to connect them like the `AppDelegate` class in the initial nib file.

Comment: yes, I added an Object and named it "Class1" and manage everything from there. In the windowController I don't do anything.. that's my first try on a mac app. I did this with the object because I had several problems using an nsviewcontroller or windowcontroller

Comment: Did you connect the text field to the outlet in your IB?

Comment: @VincentFriedrich Is there a chance for you to publish it on Github? It's really hard to find an error like this.

Answer (score 15):

`-` and `+` don't mean public or private

`-` stands for methods that you can call on objects of the class and

`+` stands for methods that can be called on the class itself.

Comment: ahh okay.. does that differ from java or did I get something totally wrong?

Comment: there basically are no private functions in objective-c... every function defined in the header is public... if you still want to define private functions so that they are mentioned somewhere, you add a block within your .m like described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/651852/232812

Comment: Good answer, though technically these are *methods*, not functions.

Comment: In other words, `+` means static and `-` means non-static

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access an instance variable with a class method. You should convert the `+setLabel:` method to `-setLabel:`, and call it like this:

```
[_myClass1Variable setLabel:@"Test"];
```

Additionally, what's `-setStringValue`? If you're just trying to change the text of the `UILabel` you need to call `-setText:`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `label` would be a NSTextField, and you are tring to set its value without loading that XIB, resulting that your awakeFromNib is not getting called. And the outlet will not be bound that that `label`.